# Unable to parse custom Java date: Can I set it to a default year?

Tags: java, date, datetime

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("h:mm a z - d MMMM")
                    .toFormatter()
                    .withLocale(Locale.US);

            String test = "7:00 PM EST - 14 April";
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(test, formatter2);
```

It throws this exception

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '7:00 PM EST - 14 April'
> could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from
> TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=14, MonthOfYear=4},ISO,America/New_York
> resolved to 19:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed

But you can see that it correctly parsed out all the components. What's the issue?

Comment: What's the year?

Comment: @aled oops! Can I set it to a default year?

Comment: Edit the Question's title and body to make clear that you are asking for how to set a default year in the formatter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the construction of a `LocalDateTime` requires a *year* to be present, but your time string does not.

You can instruct the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to default to some value if some element is absent, using `parseDefaulting`.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2023)
    .appendPattern("h:mm a z - d MMMM")
    .toFormatter()
    .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `ChronoField`.